# How to use the EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR kernel option?

Tags: kernel, gentoo, firmware

I am using Gentoo, and I need to load an extra firmware to get my USB Wifi adapter work. I found an `EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR` kernel option, but I do not understand if it is used during compile time only or if it is effective after the new kernel is used. My WiFi adapter chip is Atheros, and according to [this page](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ar9170), I have to put the firmware to the **right place**. On Ubuntu, I found the `/lib/firmware` directory as it is indicated in that page, but I cannot find that directory on Gentoo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://www.kernel.org/doc/menuconfig/drivers-base-Kconfig.html

In particular:

- EXTRA_FIRMWARE "allows firmware to be built into the kernel, for the
  cases where the user either cannot or doesn't want to provide it from
  userspace at runtime"
- EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR "controls the directory in which the kernel build system
  looks for the firmware files listed in the EXTRA_FIRMWARE option.
  The default is the firmware/ directory in the kernel source tree,
  but by changing this option you can point it elsewhere, such as
  the /lib/firmware/ directory or another separate directory
  containing firmware files".

By the way, as far as getting your wireless card working, have you taken a look at these pages?:

- http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/TL-WN821N
- http://bugs.gentoo.org/278385

Comment: Thanks. I checked the Gentoo WiKi. I found the patch was to apply to the `2.6.30` kernel, but even the latest kernel does have that patch applied. Why? I was trying to look for a way that does not require a private kernel patch.

Comment: Another question, why the '/lib/firmware' is the right place? Is there any way/possibility it is changed? How?